# Anchor html speed with jquery

Tags: jquery, html, anchor, pagespeed

I use this code to format my anchor speed, but it doesn't work on IE (7,8,9 & 10) and firefox. Can someone tell me what am I doing wrong and how to optimize anchor speed?

```
$('a.anchorlinks').on('click', function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            var divId = $(this).attr('href');
            var position = $(divId).position();
            $('body').animate({scrollTop: position.top}, 1000);
        });
```

Comment: What errors are produced in the Developer's Tools? (F12)

Comment: Exactly is this my problem, because i don't see any error, "error display" in IE is also activated, i use jquery 1.10, i tried with older versions, but is always the same problem

Comment: I think your `position` is nothing because you are trying to get the top position of a `href` tag.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of position, use offset()
http://api.jquery.com/offset/

Answer (score 0):

Add the CSS property for `a.anchorlinks`

```
position:relatve
```

Ya, you can try with offSet() too

Comment: I have tried this, but don't work, offset() and position(), exist any other way to setup speed of ancher's?